# How Third Party Apps are getting data without using Adwords Reporting API?

Tags: automation, google-api, reporting, google-signin, google-reporting-api

I was trying to develop an automated reporting tool for my company and its very difficult to get the Google API access, being a very large agency we are still not able to get that.

Having said that, when I tried using some other reporting tools, they retrieve all our account reports just by connecting them with one access permission (with google sign-in API).

Any idea how the third party apps are doing it so easily without any API access?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) to help you get started.

> The Google Analytics Reporting API v4 is the most advanced
>   programmatic method to access report data in [Google Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics#topic=3544906).
>   With the Google Analytics Reporting API, you can:
>
> - Build custom dashboards to display Google Analytics data.
> - Automate complex reporting tasks to save time.
> - Integrate your Google Analytics data with other business applications.

Currently, [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/#quick_start_guides) are the languages supported, sample codes were also available.

- Service application (Java, Python, PHP)
- Installed application (Java, Python)
- Web application (PHP, JavaScript)

You have also to take note these reason from the answer in [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25606671/google-analytics-access-api-without-login) why we need to have access permission:

> 1. **Security**. If the end user has your credentials he can log into your google account and have access to all your data.
> 2. **Latency**. The API is not intended to be used on page load. If your page loads depend on it it may take a long time to load for your
>      users.
> 3. **Quota**. The API has a limited quota that will extinguish fast if you query it every time a user enters your website.
> 4. **Design**. Ultimately, the API was designed to be used by yourself extracting data offline not in real time by others.